# Stop ScrollView from scrolling React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to stop a `ScrollView` from scrolling in React Native. I don't want to disable it, I just want it to stop scrolling at a specific point. When you disable a scrollview, the momentum scrolling still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [onScroll](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll) or [ContentOffset](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#contentoffset) props to get scroll position and give it conditional when it's on your stopping point and change the scrollEnabled properties to disabled